# Is there a way to search/browse my own chatroom history?

Tags: support, chat

Is there a way to browse one's own history of participation in chatrooms?

Specifically, I'd like a way to see all of my conversations that were started from a "Let us continue this discussion in chat" comment invitation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

##### Look through appropriately named chat rooms (i.e. with your username), including frozen and deleted rooms

Your best bet is going to be going through the rooms which were created for your conversations. Conversations such as you're asking about where the room is semi-auto-created for a discussion between two specific users from a post have room titles in the format "Discussion between username1 and username2". The [list of rooms in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms) can be searched by just entering something into the "filter rooms" field. So, entering your username "John Gordon" into that field and selecting to also see frozen and deleted rooms results in [this list of rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms?tab=all&sort=created&filter=John+Gordon&nohide=true).

##### Your non-deleted chat messages are shown in your [recent messages pages](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon?tab=recent&pagesize=100)

A significant stumbling block for finding what you're interested in is that most of the chat rooms are deleted, which means the chat messages are deleted and won't be displayed anywhere within the chat system other than when looking at one of the deleted rooms or its transcript.

For your non-deleted chat messages, your ["recent" message pages](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon?tab=recent) are paginated, so you can go back as far as you want, but for you there's only 2 pages of non-deleted messages ([page 2](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon?tab=recent&page=2)).

A user's recent messages page is paginated: You can add `&page=N` to the URL (you can also add `&pagesize=100`) to see whatever page you desire. Userscripts which add pagination buttons: [Stack Exchange Chat History Pagination](//github.com/spacemonaut/userscripts/tree/master/se-chat-user-history-pagination) and [Chat Pagination](//github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ChatPagination.user.js), which is also in Sam's [Chat Improvements](//github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ChatImprovements.user.js)."

Given that it's possible to increase the page size of the user's recent pages to 100 and you have < 100 non-deleted chat messages, you can see all of your non-deleted chat messages [on this page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon?tab=recent&pagesize=100).